# Wish a cleaner app for OSX

Tags: osx

I am looking for a free or paid app for cleaning Mac OS X (macOS), it is some like a manager app.

It should support these features at least.

- Clean junk files
- Optimize memory
- Manage files

Which one is a great one and matches my requirements?

Comment: Be careful with these apps. Some consider junk files any file that hasn't been open in some predetermined length of time.  This is ok as long as you are aware that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I have been recommended an app called [PowerMymac](https://www.imymac.com/powermymac/) recently, and it really helped me with issues like you suffered from. You may just have a try.

Comment: Can you add some description? Currently the answer is essentially only a link:  [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend a great app for you: [Dr. Cleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dr-cleaner-disk-mem-clean/id921458519?mt=12)

It gives your Mac a performance boost by freeing up plenty of disk space and by also clearing up your Mac’s memory, two vital processes that can affect your system performance.

For more details, see its website: [mac cleaner](https://www.drcleaner.com)

Answer (score -2):

A small and open source software.
[Clean-Me](https://github.com/Kevin-De-Koninck/Clean-Me)

Comment: A link-only answer with an incorrect link, that is a bit.ly reference (so that we don't see where we're going)? No thanks.

Comment: Note that linked github project is dead, last update year ago.